# Using Display Poll with c#

Tags: c#, .net

i'm Developing a POS systems in C#, and I have a Display Poll (serial port by USB), and i'm facing an issue when i send something to be displayed on the device.

i have the following code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    SerialPort sport = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        sport.Open();

        //Clear the Display
        sport.Write(new byte[] {0x0C}, 0,1);
        sport.Write("My System");
        //Goto Bottem Line - Most Left
        sport.Write(new byte[] { 0x0A, 0x0D }, 0, 2);

        sport.Write(textBox2.Text);
       // MessageBox.Show("Hello");

        sport.Close();



    }
```

if i use the above code the display will be like the following (not constant)

my
my s
my sy

every time something missing.

but if i uncommet the messagebox command every thing works fine.

i don't need the messagebox or any other command, What it wrong and what should i do?

Please Help

Comment: Does display protocol assume any handshaking?

Comment: i'm not sure about the handshake, if i use "Termite 3.1" tool it shows me the setting "No Handshake"